# Is it possible to cache a json file in cocos2d?

Tags: ios, caching, cocos2d-iphone

I have a project in that I need to cashe .json files. 
It's Performance will rely on it.

Is there any way possible to cache a .json file in cocos2d 2.0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, keep it in the memory (in an adequate data structure) or save it to a file & load it on demand.